# Is it correct and natural to say "I'll meet you at $100" meaning I'll accept $100 for something?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say *I'll meet you at $100* meaning I'll accept $100 for something? For example:

> The phone costs $150, but **I'll meet you at** $100 if you pay upfront.

If it's not natural, what are other ways to express it?

Comment: "at" is a common preposition for talking about prices: "The best bid is at $80".

Comment: In very modern times we also speak of a "meeting of minds", but where a buy bid is rising and a sell offer is falling in a pattern of convergence, the two amounts can be said to meet. The language of negotiation is rich. "I am sure we can come to an agreement at $100" might be a optimistic statement from either party.

Comment: It sounds like you are striking a bargain when you say that, so really depends on the context.  It implies they have explicitly asked if they can pay less, obviously you want them to pay more, so you meet in the middle.

Comment: From my humble perspective the phrase `"I'll meet you at $100."` appears to be a figurative form of speech or even borderline vernacular.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If the potential buyer had previously offered to pay *less than* $100 (e.g. $80), then it's natural to say "I'll meet you at $100". Otherwise, "I'll accept $100" is a better choice.

I think in the context of financial negotiation, "to meet" implies a compromise (usually mutual). Perhaps this diagram will be useful:

```
$80 -----> $100 <-------- $150
buyer --->   <------ seller
```

Comment: *"I'll meet you half-way"* is a pretty common metaphor used for saying that you'll split the difference between an price and an offer (or between an offer or counter-offer), but I'd say that *meeting at (a dollar-figure)* isn't necessarily as common (albeit I'd understand the intent).  The original metaphor uses the idea of physically meeting at a location that is equidistant for both parties.  I'd suggest/prefer *"I'll settle for $100"* over *"I'll meet you at $100"*.

Comment: @jimbobmcgee i'd argue that "i'll meet you at <exact value>" is perfectly understandable 
 - and indeed, a natural extension of "i'll meet you halfway" since that doesn't specify what price you want to meet at (which means it doesn't help you make a sale). and also, unless you have evidence otherwise, it seems like the phrase is used for any sort of compromise in general - see definitions in [the free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/meet+you+halfway).

Comment: ... so i probably went off on a tangent there, what i really meant to say is that to me, "meeting at <x>" and "settling for <x>" has exactly the same meaning - if anything, depending on the situation i'd avoid using "settle for" since it implies you're on the losing end of a deal. not that that'll change anything but still a *bit* negative

Comment: @somebody - Agreed - I'd understand someone using "meet you at..." just fine, which is why I only posted a comment, not another answer. I was just pointing out that it is possibly, *technically* less "natural" (for some definition of "natural"), unless you used the distance-based metaphor (half-way, part-way, etc.).

Comment: Unicode ASCII art! Oxymoron! :-)

Comment: @jimbobmcgee That "*I'll settle for $100*" works if said by the seller, but not by the buyer. The "*I'll meet you at $100*" works for both parties in the negotiation.

Comment: @PcMan - agreed; I read the question as being from the seller's point-of-view, but it is not explicit.  It is certainly the *seller* that *settles*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the two of you are approaching that 100 from above and below, respectively.

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! Could you clarify what the added value of this answer is compared to the accepted one? Otherwise, it's best not to repeat existing answers.